# Define custom UserDatabase resource inside application context.xml

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I wonder if is possible to have UserDatabase based on org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory defined inside application context.xml

if i define this resource as global in tomcat-s server.xml, it seems to be ok, but if I define same resource in application's context.xml, there seems to be problem starting the app.

The original UserDatabase resource is left intact, i want to prevent changes to server.xml or overwriting any existing tomcat conf files because in the end this is application specific resource therefore it should be defined only for the app and not globally for whole server. is this even possible to do?

resource definition in context.xml:

```
<Resource name="PeUserDatabase" 
  auth="Container" 
  description="Custom In memory user database" 
  factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" 
  pathname="conf/pe-tomcat-users.xml" 
  type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
```

usage of resource in application context.xml:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="PeUserDatabase"/>
</Realm>
```

exception:

```
SEVERE: Failed to start "org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm/1.0" realm
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Realm[UserDatabaseRealm]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:236)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:2002)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: No UserDatabase component found under key PeUserDatabase
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting override=true? . Below is an example for you.

`<Context antiJARLocking="true" override="true">`

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems that it is not possible to configure `org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm` with local resource. Resource needs to be global aka defined in server.xml

the way around this was using other type of realm, `org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm` in my case, tradeoff is that this realm is not managable at runtime and every change is visible only after restart.